# .htaccess rewrite rule matching issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so i've been tasked to make this URL work

```
foobar.com/city.homes
```

and this..

```
foobar.com/page-2/city.homes
```

with this rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).homes$      search-results.asp?area=$1&proptype=home
```

so my first try seems, logically enough i think

```
RewriteRule ^page-(.*)/(.*).homes$     search-results.asp?area=$2&proptype=home&page=$1
```

however, no matter where i put it in .htaccess, its not working the way i'm expecting it to.  it never matches the second rule unless i remove the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex are wrong and are overlapping.

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9])/([^.]+)\.homes$ search-results.asp?area=$2&proptype=home&page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.homes$ search-results.asp?area=$2&proptype=home [L,QSA]
```

Comment: so i guess how this works is that it searches backwards from the eol and does the matching that way?  i would really like to know the trick here because i spent an hours trying to get things to work :)

Comment: This is basically using better negation based regex rather than `.*`